# Signs of electromagnetic interference?

Tags: display, lcd, interference

I recently picked up a 22 inch Samsung LCD monitor, it was used but it worked perfectly when I got it. Now that its in my office, I've noticed that there are horizontal lines of "static" moving across the screen. I've been told that this is a sign of interference coming from other devices, but my computer tower is at least 1.5 feet away from the monitor, and the only other device that could be causing it is the electric fan next to me. Somehow I doubt that.

Is there any other way to tell where this interference is coming from?

Comment: Could be coming from the power.  Have you tried a different power socket (preferably on a different circuit)?  Electric fans can produce a TON of interference (at least with CRTs).  So even though you may doubt it,  what happens if you try disconnecting and/or moving the fan? :)

Comment: I've unplugged the fan and moved it, and the problem still persists. I'm thinking now that it might be the VGA cable, but it looks intact. I'll see if I can't dig up another cable and try it out.

Comment: hook the lcd up to another computer to see if the problem persists.

Comment: Re @Keltari's comment, or move it elsewhere. Try in another room, at home. See if turning off other electric appliances/ligts does make a difference. I don't think it is a cable problem, a line means some kind of periodic interference with a decent frequency (frame refresh or thereabouts).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I tried out all the suggestions, moving it to another power outlet, trying it on another computer, and removing the fan, but none of them seemed to work. I then switched out the VGA cable for another one I had lying around, and boom, the problem is fixed. No more static/lines on the monitor, and everything is crystal clear.

I don't know what exactly caused the problem, but I'm guessing that the original cable was damaged (although I can't see any traces of physical damage), or that it lacks shielding. I do note that the original cable is significantly thinner than the new one that I put in. Any comments on that?

Answer (score 0):

I could completely blank out my Samsung monitor but turning on the dimmer switch on om ceiling lights.  I replaced the HDMI cables and put aluminum foil around my HDMI distribution box.  The problem is gone.

Comment: Bob please go through this https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer and better re-write the answer which reflects a question rather then answer.